# Want a page which has both login and signup option on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently learning ruby on rails through railstutorial.org. As it has shown to make login and sign-up page on different page. 
Is it possible to reuse the login page back-end code on signup page or other page easily without writing the whole code again and again.

Comment: Yes, take a look at partial views http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Sorry! I missed to mention backend code of login page.

Comment: You can create a Service Class, something like `class Authentitcator` located in `lib/services/authenticator.rb` which would hold the logic behind the authentication. Then in every of your controller's action you instance the Authenticator class and give it the params like username and password.

Comment: Backend code would remain the same, you just make sure the forms are pointed to the sign_up_path.

Comment: Great! I will go through it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Mike and MrYoshiji for your help. I just included login_path in sign up page and its working.

Comment: If their comments helped, show appreciation by up-ticking them. Wave your mouse to the right of their comment and an up arrow will show.